# splitting space-separated string in one column to two (int) columns - pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df1.head()
        time/wattage
0  1303132930 225.57
1  1303132931 226.09
2  1303132932 222.74
3  1303132933 222.20
4  1303132934 222.11
```

That has the dtype as:

```
df1.dtypes
time/wattage    object
dtype: object
```

I want to have something like this:

```
df1.head()
      time         wattage
0  1303132930      225.57
1  1303132931      226.09
2  1303132932      222.74
3  1303132933      222.20
4  1303132934      222.11
```

where time and wattage are in `'int'` and `'float'` types, respectively.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
df1[['time','wattage']] = df1['time/wattage'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
        time/wattage        time wattage
0  1303132930 225.57  1303132930  225.57
1  1303132931 226.09  1303132931  226.09
2  1303132932 222.74  1303132932  222.74
3  1303132933 222.20  1303132933  222.20
4  1303132934 222.11  1303132934  222.11
```

Those are still string/object dtype, you need to cast the correct dtype.